# Google Play Console Authentication Rejected

Tags: upload, google-play, google-play-console, pin-code

So I'm trying to upload my application on Google Play and they sent me back an email telling me that they need access to my application.
The thing is that I'm using Twilio OTP (One Time Password) service when a user try to register or login and I gave them a valid number, but they need the PIN(Personal Identification Number) from the message so they send me an error telling me that they need a valid account to let them access without any PIN number.